# What is the correct configuration to run intern tests against Safari browser on Sauce Labs

Tags: selenium, safari, intern, saucelabs

Based on https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/, configured the intern config to run functional tests against Safari browser:

```
      environments : [ {
                    "browserName" : "safari",
                    platform : [ "OS X 10.9" ],
                    version: "7.0"
                } ],
```

However, testing does not initiate and following error is thrown:

```
SUITE ERROR
UnknownCommand: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:1290/wd/hub/session/    
{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"safari","platform":"OS X   
10.9","version":"6","tunnel-identifier":"1443465925611","selenium-  
version":"2.46.0","command-timeout":360,"idle-timeout":180}}] The requested 
resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method 
that is not supported by the mapped resource.
at Server.createSession  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/leadfoot  
/Server.js:307:15>
at <node_modules/intern/lib/executors/Runner.js:174:22>
at retry  <node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:695:13>
at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:393:15>
at runCallbacks  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:11:11>
at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:317:4>
at run  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Promise.ts:237:7>
at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/nextTick.ts:44:3>
at process._tickCallback  <node.js:355:11>
```

Comment: Your configuration says `version: "7.0"` but what was posted indicates `"version": "6"` which isn't available.  Are you sure the configuration in the question was used to produce the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The desired capability "platform" should work if the value is not contained in brackets. Here is a set of capabilities for OSX 10.9 with Safari version 7 that will work.

```
  environments : [ {
                "browserName": "safari",
                "platform": "OS X 10.9",
                "version": "7.0"
            } ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
capabilities.setCapability("safari.cleanSession", true);

SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
capabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);

//For Sauce
capabilities.setCapability("platform", "OS X 10.11");
capabilities.setCapability("version", "9.0");

webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(sauceURL, capabilities);
```